# MySQL sum from two joined tables and multiple rows

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am having a problem with the following query:

```
SELECT sum(((ordered_items.price + ordered_items.vat) * ordered_items.qty) + orders.postage_price + orders.postage_vat) as total_price
FROM orders
JOIN ordered_items
ON orders.id_orders = ordered_items.order_id
GROUP BY orders.id_orders
```

The idea is to bring back the total price of an order including the postage.

- ordered_items - includes all the items ordered (so there can be multiple rows)
- orders - includes the postage price of the order (there will only ever be one row per order here)

The problem I'm having is that if an order contains multiple items in 'ordered_items' the above sum counts the postage in 'orders' multiple times.

How can I rewrite this query so the postage is only counted once?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you grouping by the PK from the `orders` table?  If so, just move the postage to outside the `SUM()`.

Comment: I missed the GROUP BY off, but yes simply moving the postage outside the SUM() works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, you just need to move the postage_price and vat out of the aggregate and GROUP BY them:

```
SELECT sum((ordered_items.price + ordered_items.vat) * ordered_items.qty) + orders.postage_price + orders.postage_vat as total_price
FROM orders
JOIN ordered_items
ON orders.id_orders = ordered_items.order_id
GROUP BY orders.postage_price, orders.postage_vat
```

Comment: That almost worked but I had to replace 'GROUP BY orders.postage_price, orders.postage_vat' with 'GROUP BY orders.id_orders' - works as I wanted now. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT items.total + orders.postage_price + orders.postage_vat) AS total_price
FROM orders
JOIN (SELECT order_id, SUM((ordered_items.price + ordered_items.vat) * ordered_items.qty) AS total
    FROM ordered_items
    GROUP BY order_id) items
ON orders.id_orders = items.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add grouping

```
GROUP BY ordered_items.order_id
```

Comment: Yes sorry I missed that out of the statement by accident